# For loop in jquery template?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know if it is possible to put a for loop into a jquery template?

For example if I have something like `${userCap}` where the value of userCap is 10, how could I add a for loop to the template to add options to a select while i is less than userCap?

```
<select>
{{for(i=1; i<=userCap; i++)}}
<option value="${i}">${i}</option>
{{/for }}
</select>
```

As per Bergi's request - the plugin I am using is... jQuery Templates https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Comment: oh yeah? then whats this - https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't know that one of those plugins (there are many) was once "official" because it was maintained by the jQuery team.

Comment: @Josethehose it's a jquery plugin. no need to be rude... there are no jquery templates.

Comment: You know the plugin you're linking to hasn't been in active development for a couple of years now?

Comment: @LuudJacobs for 4 years... and it was beta back then.... i wouldn't use it.

Comment: I have to use it because of its file size. I have been instructed to do so. Otherwise I wouldn't. Anyways, if anyone else has something helpful to add then it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Josethehose DON'T use it. you will be frustated! it's old and was beta back then. use a real templating engine like handlebars or something else

Comment: Philipp, Bergi - apologies for coming across as rude. It was not my intention.

Comment: Believe me I would. Handlebars was my first choice for this. But unfortunately after a site speed audit I'm forced to use it :(

Comment: Doesn't look like that template supports a looping syntax. But [according to the (archived) docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20120921051806/http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/), you can iterate collections - you'd only need to build an `[1, 2, …, userCap]` array.

Comment: @Josethehose: which speed auditor can force you to use a particular plugin? Btw, if the previous one was too slow, you can always use raw JS, which also gives you full flexibility :-)

Comment: I agree with you. It was the tech architect's call on this particular project. I might go back and have a word with him

Comment: Ok, had a chat with the man - and we are going to try lodash as it seems it is already being used elsewhere in the site :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/jquery-templates-supported-tags) suggests it cannot.

However you can use `each`:

```
<select>
{{each(i) values}}
    <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjv96L5L/2/)

Comment: Many thanks. Problem is userCap in my example isn't an array, so not sure if it would work

Comment: Look at the fiddle. You can use usercap to create the array. ,[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/pjv96L5L/3) it

Comment: Thanks, it saved me couple hours of searching solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a plugin for that, it is way easier to roll a format function and use it instead. Format would replace `"{0}-{1}-{2}".format('a','b','c')` to `"a-b-c"`.

```js
$(function() {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number] : match;
    });
  };
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#options").append("<option value='{0}'>{0}</option>".format(i));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="options" name="options">
</select>
```